# In process builder how to create a new criteria that checks if the Case owner has changed and also that the owner is not a Queue

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Ok, so in a process builder i have to create a new criteria that checks if the Case owner has changed (which i have this part) but also that the owner is not a Queue that part i'm stuck on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check that **Owner Id** is updated and *Id* in **Owner Id (Queue)** is not same as **Owner ID**:

[image]